# Chaining of operators with .|> in Julia

Tags: julia, operators, chain

I have an expression

```
 [1:5;] .|> [x->x^2, inv, x->2*x, -, isodd]
```

taken from Julia documentation.

The output is

```
5-element Vector{Real}:
    1
    0.5
    6
   -4
 true
```

Can somebody explain the chain of operations on each elements `1:5` in detail.
I did not understand why 1 is converted to 1 and 5 is converted to true.

Comment: What result were you expecting? Something like `foldl(∘, reverse([x->x^2, inv, x->2*x, -, isodd])).([1:5;])`?

Comment: Don't write `[1:5;]`, it creates an unnecessary intermediate vector. Just use `(1:5)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are doing is equivalent to:

```
julia> (x -> x^2)(1)
1

julia> inv(2)
0.5

julia> (x -> 2x)(3)
6

julia> -(4)
-4

julia> isodd(5)
true
```

i.e. you are broadcasting a container with five functions to it over a range with five elements. The first function is then applied to the first element of your range, the second function to the second element etc.